# Arduino Char Arrays Weird Symbols

Tags: arduino, char, arduino-uno, chararray

So in my arduino programm I am working with char arrays in a function. I try to save them globally, but no matter how I do it, the global arrays contain only part of the original array and a ton of gibberish symbols.

```
char* naam;
char* compliment;
byte color = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  
  doStuff();
  
  Serial.println(naam);
  Serial.println(compliment);
  Serial.println(color);
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void doStuff(){
  String raw = "1234567890123456,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,0";
  int i = raw.indexOf(",");
  int j = raw.indexOf(",", i+1);
  char a[i+1];
  char b[j-i];
  
  raw.substring(0,i).toCharArray(naam, i+1);
  raw.substring(i+1,j).toCharArray(compliment, j);
  color = (byte) raw.substring(j+2,j+3).toInt();
  Serial.println(a);
  Serial.println(b);

  naam = a;
  compliment = b;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this does not work and point me in the right direction?

Comment: next time please add a few comments to your code so we can follow your thought process.

Comment: First, `naam` and `compliment` are not arrays, they are just pointers to some *undefined* memory location. Second, as @Piglet answered,`a` and `b` are uninitialized data on the stack. Third, `a` and `b` will be trashed by other stack use once `doStuff` returns. At that point, `naam` will remain pointing to garbage on the stack. Fourth, the first time around `naam` is unset, so where exactly is `toCharArray(naam, i+1)` putting the characters?  Somewhere, you need to actually allocate storage outside of the stack, and do tests to make sure your detected strings can actually fit in that storage.

Answer (score 1):

Here you create two char arrays `a` and `b`

```
char a[i+1];
char b[j-i];
```

You never assign any values to its elements befor you print them.

Hence you'll print whatever garbage is in those memory locations

#### Response to comment:

> They are filled by the "toCharArray(compliment, j);". The println(a)
> prints correctly

When you first call `doStuff`

You create two uninitialized char arrays `a` and `b`.
Then you store two substrings as char array to `naam` and `compliment`. Both uninitialized char pointers. So you're basically storing stuff in a random position in memory.

Then you print `a` and `b` which contain random garbage.

Then you store the addresses in `a` and `b` to `naam` and `compliment`.

Once `doStuff` returns a and b are out of scope. `naam` and `compliment` still point at their position but that memory is free to be used by something else.

Comment: They are filled by the "toCharArray(compliment, j);". The println(a) prints correctly